# Obtener coordenadas usando PDF.js ayuda

Tags: angular, pdf

Estoy usando el componente **ng2-pdf-viewer** de [VadimDez/ng2-pdf-viewer](https://github.com/VadimDez/ng2-pdf-viewer) y queria saber de algun mecanismo para poder obetener kas coordenadas del documento ya renderizado en pantalla al mover el cursor

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] para aprender el funcionamiento del sitio y de paso ganes tu primera medalla, 
también es muy importante que leas [Ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que esta sea bien recibida por la comunidad y aquí te dejo un [mcve]